# NSURLSession with invalid resume data

Tags: ios, download, nsurlsession, resume, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I use `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]` to config my url session.

I pause a task by calling `cancelByProducingResumeData:` to produce a resume data, and save it to the disk. When I want to restart the task, I call `downloadTaskWithResumeData:`. It works well until I restart the app.

I kill the app after I pause a task. Then I start my app again, and call `downloadTaskWithResumeData`, I found that the resume data was invalid.

I parse the resume data into NSDictionary and get the `NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath`, which is

`"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5DD071C3-9D5E-4D76-9F74-57B6C92445CB/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_IUI6kg.tmp"`.  I try to access this file, but it is not exist.

My question is how can I continue a download task using resume data after I restart my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, good question - upvoted. Can you tell me how you write data to disk if user quits the App ?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you relaunch your app, everything under tmp will be cleaned, I was experiencing the same thing, even though I tried to copy all the *.tmp, and paste back whenever app relaunches, it'll throw an error

My advice is that, you check if the *.tmp file is accessible, redownload from start if not

Comment: @LittleBobyTables, thanks a lot for editing my answers to be a lot nicer. Mark, I endup using [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) to achieve what you & I both had in mind

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can I rebuild the resumeData and replace the the *.tmp file path?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem. I found that sandbox path will change after the application restart in iOS8. But the resumeData record the old sandbox path, that let the download task can’t find the resumeData. So I update the sandbox path recorded in sandbox by key ‘**NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath**’, it does work:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:resumeDataPath];
NSString *resumeDataFileName = [dic[@"NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath"] lastPathComponent];
NSString *newTempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *newResumeDataPath = [newTempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:resumeDataFileName];
[dic setValue:newResumeDataPath forKey:@"NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath"];
[dic writeToFile:resumeDataPath atomically:YES];
```